# How to check if an excel column text contain specific list of words withouot using IF statement?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to check if X2 contains any of the text values given in AB2:AB7 and if matches then it  returns the corresponding AC value.

I could use below nested IF formula, or would there be any other formula I can achive this easily. I do not want to use VBA loop. Only looking for an Excel formula.

[image]

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(AB2,X2)),AC2,IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(AB3,X2)),AC3,IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(AB4,X2)),AC4,IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(AB5,X2)),AC5,IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(AB6,X2)),AC6,IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(AB7,X2)),AC7,"Not Matching"))))))
```

Comment: So your formula fails for cell A3 on 3 counts AAA, BBB and CCC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With ***Office 365*** give a try on-

```
=@FILTER($F$2:$F$7,ISNUMBER(SEARCH($E$2:$E$7,A2)))
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect. That's exactly what I wanted. Thanks a lot.